# build parsec 1.0 with gcc 4.6

Tags: c++, gcc, build

I was trying to build the PARSEC benchmark version 1.0 from Princeton, it was released around 2008, so as expected, there were some backward compatibility issues when I tried to build it with gcc-4.6.

I've been searching on the web but couldn't find if there's some flag that could run gcc in a "backward compatible" mode? Is there anyway to workaround this? I really don't want to fix the source codes or install an older version of gcc like 4.2...

Comment: *"there were some backward compatibility issues"* - can you give 2 or 3 examples?

Comment: The first error that occurs is **error: 'free' was not declared in this scope**, which I think is because of the namespace standardization by newer C++ specs, just wonder if there's an easy and quick way to get around this.

Comment: *"because of the namespace standardization"* - I doubt it... even with newish versions of g++, you can call `free` as long as you `#include <stdlib.h>` or `<cstdlib>` (in which case you can also invoke it as `std::free`).  It's likely your old code lacks either include, and some other header it does include used to indirectly include stdlib.h.  Even if there was some backwards compatibility switch, it's implausible that it'd be used to conditionally include unnecessary headers.  I suggest you spend 20 minutes fixing such simple problems and see if it all just falls out nicely.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I agree that there might be some missing headers, but I doubt I could fix the entire source code of the PARSEC benchmark in 20 minutes (there might be other issues following even if this is fixed, like the for scope), to be honest I really think it's intractable, that's why I asked the question at first place, I might just fall back to gcc 4.2 in this case...